# Nested object structures using python dependency-injector

Tags: python, dependency-injection, inner-classes

I am trying to use python dependency-injector for nested objects and I am struggling to make it work. Basically, I have Node(node_factory, other_interface_implementations) that I want to create using FactoryAggregate. I want each Node to be able to call node_factory(type) to create instances of its children. Here is my desired code that doesn't work. Is override in my container a problem since documentation seems to say that overrrides do not work for FactoryAggregate? If yes, how do I resolve this with dependency injector? I see how to do it with Factory class, but I would prefer to keep everything in the container.

```
from typing import Dict
from dependency_injector import providers, containers

class Node:
    def __init__(
        self, node_factory: providers.FactoryAggregate,
        other_interface: providers.Object
    ):
        self.node_factory = node_factory
        self.children: Dict[str, Node] = {}
        print(other_interface.provided)

    def add_child(self, types: str):
        self.children[types] = self.node_factory(types)


class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):

    placeholder: providers.Provider = providers.Provider()

    node_factory: providers.Aggregate = providers.FactoryAggregate(
        A=providers.Factory(Node, node_factory=placeholder,
                            other_interface=providers.Object("Foo")),
        B=providers.Factory(Node, node_factory=placeholder,
                            other_interface=providers.Object("Bar")),
    )

    placeholder.override(node_factory)


def main():
    container = Container()
    root = container.node_factory("A")
```